# Unable to cast object of type 'polymorphism.vehicles' to type 'polymorphism.Car

Tags: c#

```
public class vehicles
{
    public string name = "genreal";
    public string category = "general"; 
    public virtual void type()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" my name is " + name + " my category is " + category + " I am from Vehicles class");
    }
}

public class bike : vehicles
{
    public override void type()
    {
        name = "Honda";
        category = "Bike";
        Console.WriteLine("my name is " + name + " my category is " + category + " I am from Bike class");
    }
}

public class Car : vehicles
{
    public override void type()
    {
        name = "Suzuki";
        category = "Car";
        Console.WriteLine(" my name is " + name + " my category is " + category + " I am from car class");
    }
}
```

this is my class inherited with each other now i am trying to call derived class method. we all know polymorhpism enables you to invoke derived class method through base class refrence variable at run time. but i am doing little change here i am invoking it by using parent class refrence variable and parent class object by casting

```
vehicles V = new vehicles();
((Car)V).type();
Console.ReadLine();
```

this is giving exception `Unable to cast object of type 'polymorphism.vehicles' to type 'polymorphism.Car'`
is it because we cant cast the parent clas object to the child class ? i am not sure please guide me

Comment: Correct. You cannot cast a parent class to a child class (except where the concrete class is actually of the derived type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't cast a child class from the parent class.
You need to create your var as `Car` and from there you can access the `Car` methods

```
Car c = new Car();
c.type();
```

From there you can access the father properties and the child ones.